# Proving a function is bijective and computing its inverse

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $X,Y$ be sets. Define $f: X \times Y \to Y \times X $ by $f( (x,y)
>  ) = (y,x ) $. Prove $f$ is bijective and find $f^{-1} $.

#### Attempted Solution:

If $(y,x) = ( y', x') $, then $y = y'$ and $x = x' $. So it follows that $(x,y) = (x',y') $ and shows $f$ is injective. Next, take arbitrary $(y,x) \in Y \times X $. We need to find an element $\mathbf{x} \in X \times Y $ such that $f( \mathbf{x} ) = (y,x) $. Choose $\mathbf{x} = (x,y) $ and we are done. This seem so easy that I feel I may be skipping a step. Is it correct?

As for the inverse, my guess $f^{-1}(y,x) = (x,y) $ and we show it is indeed:

$$ (f \circ f^{-1})(x,y) = f( f^{-1} (x,y) ) ) = f(y,x) = (x,y) = 1_{X \times Y}$$

$$ f^{-1} ( f(y,x) ) = f^{-1} ( x,y) = (y,x) = 1_{ Y \times X } $$

So it is indeed the inverse of $f$.

IS this correct?

Comment: Yes. . . . This is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a small mistake in the second part: you must prove that $f\circ f^{-1}=id_{Y\times X}$ and $f^{-1}\circ f=id_{X\times Y}$, but you actually tried to prove that $f\circ f^{-1}=id_{X\times Y}$ and $f^{-1}\circ f=id_{Y\times X}$ which would not really make sense.

Left aside that conceptual/notational mess, it's ok.

As an advice for the future, in this case you only needed to (correctly) prove the second half of the problem: showing a function $g$ such that $\begin{cases}f\circ g=id_{Y\times X}\\g\circ f=id_{X\times Y}\end{cases}$ was already a proof of injectivity and surjectivity (though one must be careful not to inattentively shrink the domain of the composition when doing it).